# Enviar um array de objeto da servlet para uma pagina jsp

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, jsp, servlet

preciso de uma ajuda
Tenho uma servlet que ta retornando um objeto array p com uma consulta de um select .
Gostaria de saber como faço pra exibir esse objeto na minha jsp em campos input(caixa de texto) do HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você armazena como atributo na sua requisição:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String[] array = {"gato", "rato", "pato"};
    req.setAttribute("array", array);

    // Redirecionamento feito pelo servidor
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/list.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
```

Depois você recupera no seu jsp usando **EL (Expression Language)**:

```
<body>
    <input type="text" value="${array[0]}"/>
    <input type="text" value="${array[1]}"/>
</body>
```

Iterando o array com **Scriptlets**:

```
<body>
   <% 
       String[] array = (String[])request.getAttribute("array");

       for (String nome : array) { %>
           <input type="text" value="<%= nome %>"/>
           <br/>
   <%  } %>
</body>
```

Iterando o array usando **JSTL**:

```
<body>
    <c:forEach var="nome" items="${array}">
        <input type="text" value="${nome}"/>
        <br/>
    </c:forEach>
<body>
```

Com JSTL é necessario baixar os jars [jstl-api](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/jstl-api/1.2/jstl-api-1.2.jar) e [jstl-impl](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/web/jstl-impl/1.2/jstl-impl-1.2.jar).

E também é necessário referenciar a URI do JSTL no início da página JSP para que você possa usar as taglibs:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: Resolveu seu problema?

Comment: No caso, eu tenho que usar um foreach pra percorrer o meu objeto ? é isso ?

Comment: Se você quer acessar todos os índices do array dinamicamente, sim. Você poderia usar Scriptlets ou, melhor ainda, JSTL.

Comment: Editei a resposta incluindo exemplos de como iterar arrays na página JSP.

Comment: Resolveu seu problema? Nos dê um feedback!

Comment: Oi .. deu sim. Na verdade eu estava tentando fazer isto com um objeto. Eu salvei o resultado do select em um objeto então não estava dando certo. Tive que converter meu objeto para o tipo array pra fazer isso. Mas deu certo, Obrigada !

Comment: Que bom. Se essa resposta foi a solução marque-a como solução.Para finalizar o post.